# .net core IDistributedCache redis sentinel support for master / slave

Tags: c#, redis, .net-core

I am building web apis in .net core 2.0 and deploying it on kubernetes.I would like to use IDistributedCache (with redis) with sentinel and master/slave configuration. I cant find any documentation on that. How it handles master / slave scenarios (failover case)?

Comment: I am surprised after 2 years there is still no sentinel support

Answer (score 3):

A look at the source code should tell you everything you need to know:
https://github.com/aspnet/Caching/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Redis/RedisCache.cs

If you're using the nuget extension then the IDistributedCache instance should be of type RedisCache.  You should be able to cast it:

```
    public RedisWrapperClassConstructor(IDistributedCache c)
    {
        cche = c as RedisCache;
        //since pub/sub is only supported by Redis, we need to force the issue
        if (cche == null) throw new InvalidCastException("distributed cache must be of type RedisCache");
        EnsureTheConnectionMultiplexerIsSet();
    }
```

There's an active request to have the extension expose the multiplexer as a service for dependency injection:
https://github.com/aspnet/Caching/issues/343

For now you'll have to use ugly reflection:

```
    private void EnsureTheConnectionMultiplexerIsSet()
    {
        if (_connection != null) return;
        cche.Get("startup"); //populate the connection with a dummy request
        var _connectionMultiplexorFieldInfo = typeof(RedisCache).GetField(nameof(_connection), BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        var vl = _connectionMultiplexorFieldInfo.GetValue(cche);
        if (vl != null)
        {
            _connection = (ConnectionMultiplexer)vl;
            if (_connection == null) throw new InvalidCastException("Could not cast the ConnectionMultiplexer");
        }
        if (_connection == null) throw new InvalidCastException("Could not access the ConnectionMultiplexer");
    }
```

The most important part is the exceptions.  If you update your nuget package and the underlying class changes it's field names, then you'll want to throw that exception.  The multiplexer should be shared across the application so this is a very rare instance where you might justify some reflection.

edit:  I forgot to mention how to do the sentinel stuff:
https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/pull/406

edit2:  The need for reflection is resolved now, with the newer version